# iOS get nearby devices(iPad and iPhone) list through Bluetooth

Tags: swift, bluetooth

i am working on a sample project to get list of nearby iOS devices (iPhone and iPad) through bluetooth.but list does not show nearby devices (iPad and iPhone)

what is wrong with my code.any help will be appreciated.thanks in advance

```
manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    if central.state == .poweredOn{
        manager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
    }
}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    didReadPeripheral(peripheral, rssi: RSSI)
}

func didReadPeripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, rssi: NSNumber) {
    print("peripheral name", peripheral)
    if let name = peripheral.name {
        items[name] = [ "name":name,
                        "rssi":rssi ]
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: What output do you get in the console?

Answer (score 0):

`name` property of peripheral is optional, avoid using it. Instead, use the peripheral identifier property:

```swift
peripheral.identifier.uuidString
```

Answer (score 0):

The peripheral names are usually not resolved during discovery. You can try using the method peripheralDidUpdateName: to get the name of the peripheral.

You can refer this [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheraldelegate/1518801-peripheraldidupdatename?language=objc) for more information.